# How to make an already existing Docker volume accessible from host?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-volume

I have a Docker container with a volume that stores a lot of my Jenkins data. I want these files accessible from the host. Specifically, I want a directory in my volume to be shared with some folder on my host. Is this a bindmount, docker volume, or service create issue? How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host system can't(*) directly access volume data.  If the container is already running, you can [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) the data from the container to the host

```
docker cp jenkins:/var/jenkins_home ./jenkins
```

If it's not, then you can use the procedure in [Backup a container](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-a-container) to copy it from the named volume

```
docker run --rm -v jenkins_home:/jenkins -w / \
  busybox \
  tar cf - jenkins \
| tar xf -
```

Either way, you'll now have a directory `./jenkins` on your host that you can bind mount into a new container

```
docker run -v "$PWD/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home" ... jenkins/jenkins
```

and you can delete the now-unused volume.

If you have a Compose-based setup, you can use and [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) to simplify the export.  There doesn't seem to be a `docker-compose` equivalent to `docker cp`, but since the data you're trying to copy is in a named volume, that won't really matter.

```
docker-compose run -w /var jenkins tar cf - jenkins_home | tar xf -
mv jenkins_home jenkins
```

Then change `volumes:` in the service declaration to reference `./jenkins:/var/jenkins_home` instead of the named volume, and delete the named volume in the top-level `volumes:` block.

(*) If you're on a native-Linux host, there is a path inside Docker-internal storage that contains the volume content as an ordinary directory, but looking inside the Docker-internal storage isn't usually a best practice.